# rails with mongoid - is there an analog to .loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

In a rails / mysql app, there is a method that lets you check if an associated object has been loaded, or if your referencing it will trigger a database query:

```
a = Author.first
b.books.loaded?
```

But in mongoid, there is no such method.  Is there another method in mongoid that does something similar?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is

```
_loaded?
```

For some reason SO demands I add more filler, even though the above is the correct answer, so here you go.  Here's the opening line from The Great Gatsby, which I love:

```
In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice 
that I’ve been turning over in my mind ever since.  “Whenever you 
feel like criticizing any one,” he told me, “just remember that 
all the people in this world haven’t had the advantages that you’ve had.”
```